# Sending email at the click of a text element

Tags: php, ajax, email, automation, onclick

I need to make a text element that would generate an email to the admin on click.

I was looking for various solutions and came up with the following code that I compiled from various bits found on stackoverflow.

I don't know php, javascript,  jquery, just html.

JQuery that I put before `</head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clicked').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mail.php",
            success: function(){
            $('.clicked').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
 </script>
```

PHP that I put in mail.php which is in public_html

```
 <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to      = 'mail@mail.com';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}
 ?>
```

HTML

```
<span class="clicked">TEST</span>
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: There's no data in your `$_POST` so `if ($_POST)` might not evaluate to `TRUE`. Try to put some data in your AJAX call. What you could also do is add `else echo 'Email NOT sent.';` to your `mail.php` script.

Comment: like data:dataString? Well, nothing happens, literally.

Comment: No, more like `data: { test: "test" },`. Just saying 'nothing happens' is not good enough (sorry). See if there are any message in the browser console window, there probably are. See: https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/how-open-browser-console-view-errors As to my second point: Have you tried that, and then used `mail.php` directly in your browser?

Comment: I added your part and   `success: function (result) { alert("You clicked");` and now I get the on screen alert. The consoles are empty for both of the cases.

Comment: Good, that's progress. I see you also added `result` in the success function, which should be there. Now go and test the `mail.php` file as I have suggested twice: Make sure it always echo's a text so you can see it does something, anything. You test it by entering it in your browser address bar directly!

Comment: You could even replace `mail.php` by something as simple as `<?php echo "Hello world!";` so you know it works (not sending an email, but still). And also change the success function to `success: function (result) { alert(result);` so you can see what you got back from `mail.php`.

Comment: Yes, I did that, the mail.php results in a blank page with no message, there are no console errors. Wait, I'll check your latest suggestion.

Comment: It works :) Thank you so much, I wish I could do an upvote somehow.

Comment: You actually are receiving the emails? Nevermind the votes, I don't care about those.

Comment: Yes, I am. I was editing the different version of the mail.php that was lost in a separate directory. I could really do upvotes, but I can't I think, because of the reputation. You definitely derserved it from my side.

Comment: Well, what matters is that you got it working.